# Where can I download sys/types.h, sys/socket.h, netinet/in.h, arpa/inet.h, and sockaddr?

Tags: c

Where can I download the following header files for dev c

sys/types.h
sys/socket.h
netinet/in.h
arpa/inet.h

and also the structure

sockadder and it's derivatives?

Comment: For which implementation? Linux, MSVC, FreeBSD, Solaris all have their own version...

Comment: Looks like you are studying Unix socket programming. These are part of Berkeley sockets if I remember correctly. Don't know where you'll get them. In Linux, should be part of some package. No idea about Windows.

Comment: If you are on a *nix machine they probably live under `/usr/include/`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why you need to *download* these specific files, since they should come with your compiler suite in most modern systems.

You should also keep in mind that they can be radically different depending on your platform and that those files often `#include` other non-standard files (which `#include` others and so on). This could make those files very hard to parse and understand.

That said, from some indeterminate version of Linux:

http://linux.die.net/include/sys/types.h

http://linux.die.net/include/sys/socket.h

http://linux.die.net/include/netinet/in.h

http://linux.die.net/include/arpa/inet.h

If you are going to replace missing files, consider getting/reinstalling a proper compiler suite and any developer packages your are missing.

If you want to look at the structure definitions you should definitely be looking at the documentation rather than the actual implementations. That way you avoid tying your code to private definitions e.t.c. that can change between systems.

EDIT:

Just to confirm some of my comments above, `struct sockaddr` for said version of Linux is defined piece-by-piece in:

http://linux.die.net/include/bits/socket.h

http://linux.die.net/include/bits/sockaddr.h

Answer (score 1):

What SDK are you working with? For Linux you get these files as part of your core C sdk. For Windows it comes with the SDK as well. If you just want a quick and dirty look at *some* header files I use http://www.google.com/codesearch.

Answer (score 0):

Those **headers** (not *header files*) are part of the implementation. They need not be real files.

If your implementation does not provide them, you're out of luck.

If your implementation provides them as real files and you deleted them, reinstalling the compiler might work.

If your implementation provides them as real files and you cannot reinstall the compiler your approach might work. Sorry, I have no idea where to download the files --- or why would anyone copy the files somewhere in the first place.

Comment: "Header files" is perfectly OK. http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22C+Headers%22&word2=%22C+Header+Files%22 - And what do you mean by "they need not be real files"?

Comment: @Roddy: that googlefight thing does not mean anything. Check 6.4.7 in the C Standard ( http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/standards ) --- PDF ( http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf )

Comment: **headers** go between `<>`; **header files** go between `""`. **headers** are provided by the implementation; **header files** are provided by the programmer. **headers** can be a part of the binary compiler, or their information can be known by the compiler without any other support.

Comment: Thanks, for explaining. I now understand the distinction. However the files he lists aren't described as /standard/ headers so could equally well be header files? And, are there any real-world  implementations where headers are NOT real files?

Comment: @Roddy: you're right. I saw *sys/socket.h* and immediately envisioned the surrounding `<>`. If they are plain regular header files, they should be able to be downloaded and used (with the corresponding implementation files) on every compiler system out there. But then, why would someone ask for just the header files? They **need** both the header files and the code files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are trying to compile a source code for the *nix platform under another, such as Windows. This approach won't do you any good. Remember that you'll need the libraries of those headers and they are not portable.

Install a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu on your PC to do this kind of development.

Answer (score -1):

```
do:
apt-get install gcc-4.2
```